# Is there a meaningful difference betwen formulating categories via hom-sets vs. via assigning domains and codomains to morphisms?

Tags: category-theory

I usually see categories defined as having a class of objects, a class of morphisms, and operations that send each morphism to its domain and its codomain. I tend to find it more natural to think of a category as having a class of objects, and an assignment, to each pair of objects, of a hom-class. In material set theoretic foundations, the former kind of category always uniquely defines one of the latter kind of category, but the latter kind of category need not have disjoint homs and hence need not determine a category by the former definition. I usually handwave this, but I do wonder: Can this ever be the source of an actual problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean, it should not be a problem : category theory is itself a way of stating that in set theory, names should not matter! If you want to have a morphism  $f : x \to y$ and another morphism also called $f : a \to b$, in order to consider the class of morphisms, you have to take the disjoint union of all hom-classes. In this disjoint union, the two elements become distinguishable (or in categorical terms, you take a coproduct, although it might not be correct to state it like this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any category $\mathbf{A}$ in the second sense you always have a category $\mathbf{B}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbf{A}$ and is such that its hom-sets are disjoint. The construction of $\mathbf{B}$ is as follows,

- its objects are the same as that of $A$
- for each $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $f\in \operatorname{hom}_{\mathbf{A}}(A,B)$ for some $\mathbf{A}$-objects $A,B$ the corresponding $\mathbf{B}$-morphism is defined by $(A,f,B)$. In other words, $f\in \operatorname{hom}_{\mathbf{A}}(A,B)$ iff $(A,f,B)\in \operatorname{hom}_{\mathbf{B}}(A,B)$.

Since the categories are isomorphic. You don't really lose anything important so long as you are focusing only on the categorical properties. But having disjoint hom-sets sometimes gives you an advantage by letting you prove things more easily. Whereas when you are trying to show that some mathematical structure is a category, it is easier to show *that* by appealing to the later definition.

As a final remark, note that I kind of cheated when I said that, "You don't really lose anything important so long as you are focusing only on the categorical properties." because 'categorical properties' are precisely those properties of a category that are preserved by categories isomorphic to it. So, a more precise answer to your question would depend on the precise sense of the term "important".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I feel like I should probably accept this answer, since it basically does answer my question as written, but I guess my qualms also include, like, generalized cases? Particularly: 1. the definition of an internal category resembles the first notion I described, while the definition of an enriched category resembles the second—is there a reason why that has to do with some difference between them?

Comment: and 2. In foundations with subtler notions of equality than FOL—particularly ones w/ both definitional & propositional equality—it seems like definition style #1 might be straight-up *wrong*, because you'd have to condition the type of composition on a propositional rather than definitional equality? But I don't know!

Comment: @sarahzrf: Well, to be honest, I don't really know much about these notions to answer in sufficient detail. In this case, it is best to wait for people who are more knowledgeable than me in this subject. Also let me just mention that there are two chatrooms [Category Theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68360/category-theory) and [Homotopy Theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9417/homotopy-theory) where also you can post your question.